# Break nested loop until next condition is meet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, foreach

I have the following code I am taking a list and equally dividing it across three columns:

```
<div>
    @{
        double num = listing.Count() / 3.0;
        double blockSize = Math.Ceiling(num);
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling(listing.Count() / blockSize); i++)
        {

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @for (int j = i * (int)blockSize; j < (i * blockSize) + (int)blockSize && j < listing.Count(); j++)
                {
                    /// How can I only display this header once?
                    foreach(string letter in letters)
                    {
                        if (letter.ToLower() == listing.ElementAt(j).Title.Substring(0,1).ToLower())
                        {    
                            <h5 class="title"><a name="@letter.ToLower()">@letter.ToUpper()</a></h5>
                        }
                    }


                    <p><a href="#">@listing.ElementAt(j).Value</a></p>

                }                                    
            </div>
        }                       
    }
</div>
```

My question is how can I code the nested foreach loop to only be true once per letter match?  Producing an output like:

```
<div class="row colIndentTop">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h5 class="title"><a name="a">A</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Alice</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Amy</a></p>


        <h5 class="title"><a name="d">D</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">David</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="f">F</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Frank</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="i">I</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Ibrahim</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h5 class="title"><a name="n">N</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Nancy</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="o">O</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Olive</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="p">P</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Paul</a></p>                        
        <p><a href="#">Patrick</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p><a href="#">Patricia</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="s">S</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Sally</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Sean</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="t">T</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Thomas</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And not:

```
<div class="row colIndentTop">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h5 class="title"><a name="a">A</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Alice</a></p>
        <h5 class="title"><a name="a">A</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Amy</a></p>


        <h5 class="title"><a name="d">D</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">David</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="f">F</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Frank</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="i">I</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Ibrahim</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h5 class="title"><a name="n">N</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Nancy</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="o">O</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Olive</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="p">P</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Paul</a></p>   
        <h5 class="title"><a name="p">P</a></h5>                     
        <p><a href="#">Patrick</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h5 class="title"><a name="p">P</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Patricia</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="s">S</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Sally</a></p>
        <h5 class="title"><a name="s">S</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Sean</a></p>

        <h5 class="title"><a name="t">T</a></h5>
        <p><a href="#">Thomas</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. There are probably far more elegant solutions to the entire code you have, but as for your specific question, you can add a simple check.

This code will add the letter value to the variable `thisLetter` and check the next foreach to make sure you letter is new (otherwise `letter != thisLetter` will fail and it will skip adding the h5)

```
var thisLetter = '';

foreach(string letter in letters)
{
    if ((letter.ToLower() == listing.ElementAt(j).Title.Substring(0,1).ToLower()) && letter != thisLetter)
    {    
        <h5 class="title"><a name="@letter.ToLower()">@letter.ToUpper()</a></h5>
    }
    thisLetter = letter;
}
```

You can clean it up a little like the following as well with continue logic, this will not create the h5 and also skip the unnecessary re-assignment of the value to `thisLetter`. As an explanation, `continue` will skip to the next iteration of the for loop without executing any of the code after the `continue` in the loop.

```
var thisLetter = '';

foreach(string letter in letters)
{
    //Note!: The if logic is 'opposite' in this structure.
    if ((letter.ToLower() != listing.ElementAt(j).Title.Substring(0,1).ToLower()) || letter == thisLetter)
        continue;

    <h5 class="title"><a name="@letter.ToLower()">@letter.ToUpper()</a></h5>
    thisLetter = letter;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly with the code in place & thanks for providing multiple solutions!

Comment: No problem! Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all sort your names (indexNavigation) by alphabet. Then do like this (may not compile, I have no IDE now):

```
<div>
    @{
        double num = listing.Count() / 3.0;
        double blockSize = Math.Ceiling(num);
        char currentLetter = '.'
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling(listing.Count() / blockSize); i++)
        {

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @for (int j = i * (int)blockSize; j < (i * blockSize) + (int)blockSize && j < listing.Count(); j++)
                {
                    var name = indexNavigation.ElementAt(j).Title;
                    if (currentLetter != name.Title.Substring(0,1).ToLower()[0])
                    {    
                        <h5 class="title"><a name="@letter.ToLower()">@letter.ToUpper()</a></h5>
                        currentLetter = name.Title.Substring(0,1).ToLower()[0];
                    }

                    <p><a href="Faculty_and_Research/Academic_Careers.html">@indexNavigation.ElementAt(j).Title</a></p>    
                }                                    
            </div>
        }                       
    }
</div>
```

Comment: While I ended up using the other solution I wanted to up vote your answer as well as it works. Thanks for the reply!